# Punbb not writing to database

Tags: php, database

So I will start from the beginning, I took it upon myself to start a forum as one I used to visit daily disappeared, I wanted to keep in touch with the regulars, that was the basic premise behind doing the forum, I had hosting for a personal website, I figured it would be easy to add it to my hosting, which had worked fine for many years, given all it was doing was running a series of WordPress sites over the years.

I assumed it would be fine hosting a small forum, how wrong I was, my first issue was installing the forum, first choice was phpbb, that wouldn't install, after 5 tried and fruitless talks with their "tech department", I gave up on phpbb, I tried vanilla forums and one  other, neither worked, someone recommended punbb, lightweight and simple.

I gave it a try, got further with it, I got to the part where you choose your db type, sql failed many times, so I settled on sqlite, it worked, forum install and I was up and running, for a few days/1 week it went pretty smooth, then I had connection errors, "this page cannot be displayed" etc, I can't remember them all, someone smarter than I suggested some proper hosting, something dedicated to this forum, so I went looking, read a few tutorials, all spoke of backing up the database, before moving, thiw is where I ran into my first big issue, I had a cloned forum installed[or so I thought] on my PC, went to back up my db and found it to be a little small, under 100kb.

I downloaded it anyway, imported it using phpmyadmin running on wampserver, it seemed to import fine, I soon realised none of my users were there, none of th eposts, nothing was, so I researched what I may have done wrong, watched many a youtube video on how to export a db using phpmyadmin with tables etc, I followed at leas 5 separate vidoes, none seemed to work, I folded and spoke to my hosts online chat, asked them to backup the db for me, they did with the exact same result, a sub 100kb sql file lacking any tables or only a few, it varied, I had them do this 3 times I think.

So I gave up for a week I think, I was stressed, I didn't get anywhere, in this time I spoke to a few people, I got a few suggestions, the most promising is that somehow my installed forum is writing/reading data from a database that isn't under my control, this seemed to be the most logical, as the forum works, but the 2 databases I see in MySQL under my control panel, desck4 I think it's called, iPage is the host I use just FYI, are either empty [the one I specified during the install of punbb] or the one I assume was created by pubb[for unknown reasons] which shows some basic info, but nothing after my initial setup, something which I don't understand is how is the forum running, if it's not writing data to either f these databases then it shouldn't function, right, so this theory makes sense, as it needs a db to work, I don't understand how it happened, but it makes sense, even to me, a complete dummy where this this stuff is concerned.

tldr; I have a forum, I can't backup db, I am confused, as are many I have asked for help, I don't know what's happening, I don't know what to ask my host for, they don't understand what I am asking, they are of no use until I can be specific in what I ask for, I came here seeking help from the massive knowledge base that is Stack Overflow.

So anything will be of help, how do I ask for help, can anyone explain in plain English for me and the host, I really want to do this myself, but it is so far beyond my current understanding.

Comment: You can probably sign up for a ready-made forum - if you are not technical then installing one and keeping up with security updates is not worth the risk. Do a web search for "forum hosting". If you really want to self-host then I suggest you get someone in to help you - this question is extremely broad, and is not suited to the Q&A format of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is in the too hard basket, I can't explain it, and so no one can actually get at what I want to do, so I won't even try and explaining it to the host, i've moved to a new host, everything is fine and dandy, sorry for not posting right, I saw how I was supposed to do it, but it made no sense to me, I am used to a more open kind of discussion.

TLDR; Issue ignored, I'm done with it.